# composer require (normal) and require --dev in one single CLI command

Tags: composer-php

How can I use `composer require vendor/normal_package` and `composer require vendor/dev_package --dev` in one single command? I want one CLI command that requires 2 packages, one into "normal" `require` and one into `require-dev` section.

Background info: I've a composer.json file like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.6.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.6.7"
    }
}
```

Those two packages always need to be updated the same time. Usually I just do a `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies` which works fine.

But sometimes I explicitly want to require a new minimum version, and I want to do it in a shell script in order to update multiple projects at once (no manual editing of `composer.json`). I can't run the two commands
`composer require drupal/core:^8.6.10 
composer require webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.6.10`
consecutively, because they depend on each other.

How can I require a normal and a dev package in one single command?

Comment: i guess drupal/core wont depend on the dev package drupal-core-require-dev. so you can run consecutively: ```composer require drupal/core:^8.6.10 && composer require webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.6.10```

Comment: Actually they do depend on each other, I can NOT run the two commands consecutively.

Comment: no they do not depend on each other (that would be a circular dependency which would be bad anyway) the above command from @ivoba is correct

Comment: OK then, the software I use has a bad circular dependency, I repeat: I CAN NOT run the two commands consecutively

Comment: Can you explain this circular dependency? drupal/core has definetly no dependency on webflo/drupal-core-require-dev see: https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/54a532cedfe09f14ef13d8960fc96ec473bedfc7/core/composer.json

Comment: I'm using the [Drupal composer template](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) (this is related, but not the same as default Drupal). When I run `composer require drupal/core:^8.6.10` I do get this output:

Comment: `Problem 1
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.6.2 requires drupal/core 8.6.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.6.2 requires drupal/core 8.6.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for webflo/drupal-core-require-dev (locked at 8.6.2, required as ^8.5) -> satisfiable by webflo/drupal-core-require-dev[8.6.2].
`

Comment: And I'm quite certain its not a problem with minimum stabilty, because it does work when I update both `composer.json` version entries manually and then run composer.

Comment: ok i see. i think --update-with-dependencies works also with require. can you try: ```composer require webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.6.10 --update-with-dependencies```

Comment: `- webflo requires drupal 8.6.10 -> satisfiable by drupal[8.6.10].
  - don't install drupal 8.6.10
  - remove drupal 8.6.2
  - don't install drupal 8.6.2
  - webflo 8.6.x-dev requires drupal 8.6.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal[8.6.x-dev].
  - webflo 8.7.x-dev requires drupal 8.7.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal[8.7.x-dev].
  - Can only one: drupal[8.6.x-dev, 8.6.2].
  - Can only one: drupal[8.7.x-dev, 8.6.2].
  - request drupal (locked at 8.6.2, required as ^8.5) -> satisfiable by drupal[8.6.2].
  - request webflo ^8.6.10 -> satisfiable by webflo[8.6.10, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev].` (trimmed)

Comment: ok the problem is described here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3387
so i'd say its not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188892/discussion-between-ivoba-and-hudri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have got a circular dependency in your `composer.json` and that dependency is split across `require` and `require-dev`, then it currently is not possible to update and set a new min version with just one command. But I've found a workaround that saves *a lot* of time by using the require-command with `--no-update` option.

Below is the code I'm currently using (`drupal/core` is the normal package, `webflo/drupal...` is the dev package, version `^8.7.1` is the new minimum version I want to enforce):

```
# include both packages in the require section, but don't update
# this is much faster than normal require with update
composer require --no-update drupal/core:^8.7.1 webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.7.1

# move the dev package back into the require-dev section
composer require --dev --no-update webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.7.1

# now run the update, this will take some time (you can not use --no-dev here)
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.7.1 more_stuff/*

# optional: remove the dev-packages again (this is quite fast too)
composer install --no-dev
```

I won't mark the question as answered though, because this is just a time-saving workaround and not a real solution.